# Fade object to invisible after tweening position is finished

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to perform a tweening position for this object, and once it is finished, fade it out... Right now I am just hiding it when finished.

```
this.tweenBox2.onUpdate(function () 
{
            that.box.position = a;
            that.box.Show();
});
this.tweenBox2.onComplete(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < that.box.children.length; i++) {
                 that.box.children[i].visible = false;
            }
            that.box.position = new THREE.Vector3().copy(storagePos);
});
```

Here is what is inside box.children[0]

```
THREE.Mesh
```

**webglActive
:
true
__webglInit
:
true
_modelViewMatrix
:
THREE.Matrix4
_normalMatrix
:
THREE.Matrix3
castShadow
:
false
children
:
Array[0]
eulerOrder
:
(...)
frustumCulled
:
true
geometry
:
THREE.Geometry
id
:
4672
material
:
THREE.MeshLambertMaterial
matrix
:
THREE.Matrix4
matrixAutoUpdate
:
true
matrixWorld
:
THREE.Matrix4
matrixWorldNeedsUpdate
:
false
name
:
""
parent
:
Box
position
:
THREE.Vector3
quaternion
:
THREE.Quaternion
receiveShadow
:
false
renderDepth
:
null
rotation
:
THREE.Euler
rotationAutoUpdate
:
true
scale
:
THREE.Vector3
up
:
THREE.Vector3
useQuaternion
:
(...)
userData
:
Object
uuid
:
"9C6DC789-20D0-4F9F-88B6-CDA9A2C372B9"
visible
:
true
__proto**
:
THREE.Object3D

The material is created this way:

```
var box = boxModel.scene.children[3].children[0].clone();
box.traverse(function (child) 
{
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) 
    {
        child.material = child.material.clone();
    }
});
```

Comment: I see you're cloning a material, but when you first create it are you setting transparent to true?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the material for your box you need to set its transparency to true:

```
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00, transparent: true} );
```

I'm using a PhongMaterial but it doesn't matter.

Then on your onUpdate function you can change its opacity as you do for its position:

```
this.tweenBox2.onUpdate(function () 
{
            that.box.position = a;
            //This will fade the opacity from 0 to 1
            //NOTE: I'm considering "box" as a THREE.Mesh
            that.box.material.opacity = 0;

            that.box.Show();
});
```

I don't think you'll need onComplete function.

**Update 1:**
I've created a global variable which stores the opacity value:

```
var opacityVar = 1;
```

Then the fadeOut function:

```
function fadeOut(){

    if( opacityVar >= 0){

        mesh.material.opacity = opacityVar;
    }
}
```

And in the render function I'm updating the opacity var and calling the fadeOut, which you should call in you onComplete function:

```
function render() {

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    opacityVar -= 0.01; //Update opacity var

    fadeOut(); //Call FadeOut 

}
```

Comment: tween does not work like that, it would set opacity to 0 directly, but thank you for the property opacity.

Comment: Sorry I'm using another Tween library which performs tweens fx over time. Anyway I'm updating the answer with a function that can help you out

Comment: Thank you, I realized that changing its opacity does not do anything, maybe because it is a child of another object which opacity is 1 all the time? would you know how would it work then?

Comment: Please do a: console.log( that.box.children[0] ) and post the result (maybe editing your question). So I can see what's in there :)

Comment: TRANSPARENT had to be set in TRUE. Fixed. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes I wrote it in the first answer, please accept it if you found ot useful ;)